# UIDocumentPickerViewController only showing recents tab

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have been trying to implement a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in SwiftUI without much luck. When I present the view in a sheet, all that is there is a blank "recents" tab (as shown below), even though there are files in the simulator. How can I pick from iCould drive or "on my iPhone"?

FilePicker.swift

```
struct FilePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: FilePicker
        
        init (_ parent: FilePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            print("chosen")
            guard let documentURL = urls.first else {
                return
            }
            
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: documentURL) {
                parent.image = UIImage(data: data)
                parent.presentaionMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            else {
                return
            }
        }
        
        func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
            print("cancelled")
        }
    }
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentaionMode
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FilePicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let pickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.image, .jpeg, .png, .pdf], asCopy: true)
        return pickerViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FilePicker>) {
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var image: Image?
    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {

            ZStack{
                 //Stuff in here
            }
            .sheet(item: $activeSheet, onDismiss: loadImage) { item in
                switch item {
                
                case .photo:
                    PhotoPicker(image: $inputImage)
                case .file:
                    FilePicker(image: $inputImage)
                case .demo:
                    DemoPicker(image: $inputImage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadImage() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else {
            print("failed input image")
            return
        }
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
        showMenu = false
    }
}

enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
    case photo, file, demo
    
    var id: Int {
        hashValue
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Working fine with xcode 12.3 with iOS 14.3

Comment: There are no files shown even though I have opened them on the simulator though